# Is there a better (more sensible) way to achieve this same goal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working solution to a previous problem, but it does not *feel* like good programmer's habit. Is there a better solution or is this just the way to go?

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="answer(this)">A</li>
    <li onclick="answer(this)">B</li>
    <li onclick="answer(this)">C</li>
    <li onclick="answer(this)">D</li>
</ul>
```

And my JS:

```
window.answer = function (elm) {

    if ($(elm).is(':nth-of-type(1)')) {

        alert('elm is 1st of type');

    } else if ($(elm).is(':nth-of-type(2)')) {

        alert('elm is 2nd of type');

    } else if ($(elm).is(':nth-of-type(3)')) {

        alert('elm is 3rd of type');

    } else if ($(elm).is(':nth-of-type(4)')) {

        alert('elm is 4th of type');

    }

};
```

What this code does, is it alerts what nth child it is (for the 2nd `<li>` it alerts `elm is 2nd of type`)

In short, is there a better (more logical) way to achieve the same result? And if so, how should I implement that?

Cheers!

Comment: there is but first, it depents on what you actually want to accomplish: do you really want to know n-position of child clicked (regardless of its value A,B,C or D) or you actually want to know what child (its value wise) was clicked?

Comment: No the value doesn't matter to me, as I retrieve it from another source, I just want to know the n-position as I can then determine if its value suits something else.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/index/ Plus proper event handling via `.on`, of course.

Comment: @CBroe I see what you mean by the .index()-solution, but what do you mean by "proper event handling via `.on`"?

Comment: Using the `onclick` attribute in HTML code is "old school", and violates the separation of concerns principle. Attaching event handlers via the methods the DOM provides for this purpose is the way to go; and jQuery encapsulates that functionality (and its differing browser implementations) in its event handling philosophy, the main part of which is [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using JQuery, you may find utility to the use of `index` function :

https://api.jquery.com/index/

In your answer function, you can then add a selector for all the `li` you want to match (if you have multiple unordered lists for example), and then :

```
var zeroBasedIndex = $("your-li-selector").index(elm);
```

Keep in mind this returns a zero-based position, feel free to `++` it to find your positions back.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li data-type="1st" onclick="answer(this)">A</li>
    <li data-type="2nd" onclick="answer(this)">B</li>
    <li data-type="3rd" onclick="answer(this)">C</li>
    <li data-type="4th" onclick="answer(this)">D</li>
</ul>
```

script

```
window.answer = function (elm) {

    var type = $(elm).attr("data-type");
    var message = 'elm is ' + type + ' of type';

    alert(message);
};
```

if you can't edit the html:

```
window.answer = function (elm) {

    var type = parseInt($(elm).index()) + 1;
    switch(type)
    {
        case 1:     
        {
            type += "st";
        }
        break;
        case 2:     
        {
            type += "nd";
        }
        break;
        case 3:     
        {
            type += "rd";
        }
        break;
        case 4:
        {
            type += "th";
        }
        break;
    }


    var message = 'elm is ' + type + ' of type';

    alert(message);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>

$("#myList").on("click", "li", function() {
    alert( $(this).index() );
});
```

so, this is event delegation (you'll find it in jquery docs). what this effectively does is it attaches an event listener to your ul element, filters the target in a way that it will raise an event only when children of type li was clicked and then return index position of that child within the myList parent.